# read ESRI FileGeoDataBase with ogrinfo / sql filter on date field

Tags: sql, gdal, esri, ogr

I can read my FileGDB (ArcGIS 10.1) with GDAL-library (1.10) using ogrinfo and sql filtering datasets by FID

```
ogrinfo "...\test.gdb" -sql "SELECT edited FROM 'plz_simple_copy' WHERE fid = 1864" --debug on -dialect OGRSQL
```

or this way by OBJECTID

```
ogrinfo "...\test\plz.gdb" "plz_simple_copy" -where OBJECTID=1864
```

The result is:

```
using driver `FileGDB' successful.
Layer name: plz_simple_copy
Geometry: Multi Polygon
.....
plz (String) = 26452
quelle (String) = osm
osm_id (String) = -1187754
edited (DateTime) = 2013/07/09 17:34:49
Shape_Length (Real) = 0.401490815379519
Shape_Area (Real) = 0.00612509834536042
```

...but I need to filter the data by the date field "edited".
I tried a lot of variations e.g.

```
ogrinfo "...\test.gdb" "plz_simple_copy" -where edited = '2013/07/09 17:34:49' 
ogrinfo "...\test.gdb" "plz_simple_copy" -where edited = '2013-07-09 17:34:49'    
ogrinfo "...\test.gdb" "plz_simple_copy" -where "edited" = date '2013-07-09 17:34:49'
```

..  but I didn't get it.
Somebody has an idea how to solve that problem?

best greetings from Berlin
ralf

Comment: where do you write `ogrinfo`? In the visual studio command prompt? @ralf

Answer (score 0):

I also opened this thread in the ArcGIS Forum "File Geodatabase API" and got the answere there
http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/88662-read-ESRI-FileGeoDataBase-sql-filter-on-date-field

the right code has to be

```
ogrinfo "...\test.gdb" "plz_simple_copy" -where "edited = date '2013/07/09 17:34:49'"
```

maybe someone can need this, too